# Spring Data - Archiving best practices

Tags: spring, hibernate, concurrency, spring-data-jpa, architecture

Suppose that I have entities `Rule` and `RuleArchive`. Every time one make changes to `Rule` is is required to persist the previous state to `RuleArchiveTable`. I came around with this solution:

```java
class CustomRuleRepositoryImpl implements CustomRuleRepository {
    private final RuleRepository ruleRepository;
    private final RuleArchiveRepository ruleArchiveRepository;

    @Override
    public Rule saveAndFlushWithArchiveRecordCreated(Rule rule) {
        ofNullable(rule.getId())
            .flatMap(ruleRepository::findById)
            .ifPresent(this::createNewArchiveRecord);
        return ruleRepository.saveAndFlush(rule);
    }

    private void createNewArchiveRecord(Rule oldRule) {
        ruleArchiveRepository.saveAndFlush(
            RuleArchive.builder()
                // building the entity from 'oldRule' fields
                .build()
        );
    }
}
```

The thing I'm worried about is concurrency. Although the system is not of highload type, there could be some caveats. For example, when I read the rule with `ruleRepository` it is possible that somebody has already changed it. So, the values from the archived version and the saved rule won't be consistent.

Any ideas about this approach? Are there any better alternatives? I thought that I could just use `repeatable read` isolation (we use PostgreSQL), so it would guaranteed that the fetched records are the same during the whole transaction.

Answer (score 1):

This would prevent dirty reads:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
```

More here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation

Important to note that while isolation levels prevent dirty reads they won’t prevent race conditions - for that you would still need to use synchronized (which funnily could solve both of your problems provided only this method is doing the saving)

Comment: Thanks for the link. `synchronized` might be useful until there is only one application instance launched :(

Btw, what if `propagation` is default and `saveAndFlushWithArchiveRecordCreated` has been called from the service with a different isolation level? What is the final isolation level in this case? As far I understood, it should be the most restrictable.